# How to insert id auto increment in oracle 11g?

Tags: r, oracle, oracle11g

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure sp_tab is
    id1 number:=0;
begin
  select nvl(max(id1), 0) + 1 
    into id1 
    from DUAL;
  insert into table1
       SELECT distinct id1, '', SUBSTR(PRODUCT, 0, INSTR(PRODUCT, ' ') - 1), '' 
         FROM table2 
        WHERE PRODUCT NOT IN ('proved product', 'sample', 'graphic era', 'asa');
end;
```

Creatin procedure for inserting id in table 'table1' from table 'table2' 
using procedure,but it shows anonymous behaviour.

Comment: Your question is unclear, however on the basis of title you are in need of [SEQUENCE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6017.htm#SQLRF01314)

Answer (score 0):

Create a sequence as below:

```
create sequence id1 start with 1 increment by 1;
```

Use it in your code as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_tab
IS 
BEGIN

   INSERT INTO table1
      SELECT id1.nextval,
                      '',
                      SUBSTR (PRODUCT, 0, INSTR (PRODUCT, ' ') - 1),
                      ''
        FROM table2
       WHERE PRODUCT NOT IN ('proved product',
                             'sample',
                             'graphic era',
                             'asa');


END;
```